# NVMe drive causes another hard drive to not be detected by BIOS

Tags: hard-drive, bios, nvme

I had three hard drives installed in my computer. Two SSD and one HDD. They all worked fine. Today I tried to install a fourth hard drive, an NVMe drive. After installing the NVMe drive, the BIOS detected the NVMe drive, however it no longer detected my HDD. So I uninstalled the NVMe drive and my BIOS suddenly was able to detect my HDD drive again.

Motherboard: MSI Z97 Gaming 5

NVMe Drive: Crucial P1 SN: 2012E295D82B

Comment: Make sure you check which SATA ports and PCIe slots are active when specific configurations are used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Your motherboard's manual](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/Z97-GAMING-5.html#down-manual) says:

> * The SATA5 and SATA6 ports will be unavailable when installing a module in the M.2 port.

[Various](https://www.asrock.com/mb/intel/z97%20extreme4/) [forums](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/468468-using-m2-on-z97/?tab=comments#comment-6291846) say that the Intel Z97 chipset uses the same PCIe lanes for both the external M.2 slot and the internal SATA controller providing SATA5/6 ports, so only one of them can be online at the same time.